# Function now prints every letter instead of every word

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

```
owned   category                            weight  mechanics_split
28156   Environmental, Medical              2.8023  [Action Point Allowance System, Co-operative P...
9269    Card Game, Civilization, Economic   4.3073  [Action Point Allowance System, Auction/Biddin...
36707   Modern Warfare, Political, Wargame  3.5293  [Area Control / Area Influence, Campaign / Bat...
```

and used this function ([taken from the generous answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44092423/adding-values-to-pandas-dataframe-with-function-based-on-other-column-in-datafra)):

```
def owned_nums(games):
    for row in games.iterrows():
        owned_value = row[1]['owned']
        mechanics =  row[1]['mechanics_split']
        for type_string in mechanics:
            game_types.loc[type_string, ['owned']] += owned_value
```

to iterate over the values in the dataframe and put new values in a new dataframe called `game_types`. It worked great. In fact, it still works great; that notebook is open, and if I change the last line of the function to just `print (type_string)`, it prints:

```
Action Point Allowance System
Co-operative Play
Hand Management
Point to Point Movement
Set Collection
Trading
Variable Player Powers
Action Point Allowance System...
```

Okay, perfect. So, I saved my data as a csv, opened a new notebook, opened the csv with the columns with the split strings, copied and pasted the exact same function, and when I print `type_string`, I now get:

```
[
'
A
c
t
i
o
n

P
o
i
n
t

A
l
l
o
w
```

The only thing I could notice is that the original lists were quote-less, with `[Action Point Allowance System, Co-operative...]` etc., and the new dataframe opened from the new csv was rendered as `['Action Point Allowance System', 'Co-operative...']`, with quotes. I used `str.replace("'","")` which got rid of the quotes, but it's still returning every letter. I've tried experimenting with the escapechars in to_csv but to no avail. Very confused as to what setting I need to tweak.

Thanks very much for any help.

Comment: Don't see any code that doesn't work, or sample CSVs here.

Comment: Quick answer.. whenever you are getting chars instead of whole strings, you are iterating a level deeper. Kind of opposite of http://i2.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/000/531/557/a88.jpg.  Break your dream now !

Comment: At a guess: .csv does not understand a "list" cell type; it converts it to a string. When you load it back and iterate over it, you are iterating over a string, not a list.

Comment: I have no idea why this is being downvoted

Comment: Welcome to SO. Greet the SO h8ers. *sighs*. I thought it was a well constructed question.

Comment: `+=` on a string will append the individual characters of the string to the list. It is equivalent to `.extend()` on the list, which takes an iterable, and strings are iterable. You want `.append()` or  `+= [string]`.

Comment: @kindall But the mystery is that it's not doing that with the first csv, and I'm not using `+=` in my test function, just printing the strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way the code

```
    mechanics =  row[1]['mechanics_split']
    for type_string in mechanics:
        game_types.loc[type_string, ['owned']] += owned_value
```

can have worked is if your `mechanics_split` column contained not a string but an iterable containing strings.

Storing non-scalar data in Series is not well-supported, and while it's sometimes useful (though slow) as an intermediate step, it's not supposed to be something you do regularly.  Basically what you're doing is

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [["x","y"],["z"]]})
>>> df.to_csv("a.csv")
>>> !cat a.csv
,A
0,"['x', 'y']"
1,['z']
```

after which you have

```
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv("a.csv", index_col=0)
>>> df2
            A
0  ['x', 'y']
1       ['z']
>>> df.A.values
array([['x', 'y'], ['z']], dtype=object)
>>> df2.A.values
array(["['x', 'y']", "['z']"], dtype=object)
>>> type(df.A.iloc[0])
<class 'list'>
>>> type(df2.A.iloc[0])
<class 'str'>
```

and you notice that what was originally a Series containing lists of strings is now a Series containing only strings.  Which makes sense, if you think about it, because CSVs never claimed to be type-preserving.

If you insist on using a frame like this, you should manually encode and decode your lists via some representation (e.g. JSON strings) on reading and writing.  I'm too lazy to confirm what pandas does to str-ify lists, but you might be able to get away with `apply`ing `ast.literal_eval` to the resulting strings to turn them back into lists.

Comment: Thanks very much for the helpful explanation. I'll go ahead and accept this answer, but I'm curious: you wrote, "if you insist on using a frame like this..." What's the ideal way to store data like this if not in a dataframe so that I can easily load and work with it in the future?